# Is it a trichoderma?

Tags: mycology

I have got some fungi on a polypore. Can it be a trichoderma?
[image]

Comment: It certainly could be, given how prevalent they are, but fungi are nearly impossible to identify visually like this. You need to look at its microscopic structure, run various biochemical assays, and ultimately do sequencing, just like with bacteria.

Comment: There are fungal morphologists but they do require microscopes.  some penecilia also have this color... they are also very common... :)

Comment: The green colour is darker than I see with fresh Trichoderma infections. It looks like an old infection. My experience limited to growth on coffee grounds and cocopeat.